# Bash and grep variable regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need to get 'test2' value from a json string in bash. The only way I found with the minimum of dependency is to use perl regexp pattern like this:

```
echo '{"test1":1119,"test2":1118 }' | grep -Po '"test2":\K\d+'
1118
```

However, How could I achieve grep with a variable ? The following wont work becase $param is within single quote. I can't find a way around this

```
param="test2"
echo '{"test1":1119,"test2":1118 }' | grep -Po '"$param":\K\d+'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: With some kind of concatenation maybe.

Comment: Put it inside double quotes. BTW, there's a tool called `jq` that can be used to parse JSON in bash.